# Works in ghci but not in the file

Tags: haskell

when I try something in ghci after loading the file like `putStrLn $ showManyP "%d" 10`
it works but why this don't work when I write it in the file
`main = putStrLn $ showManyP "%d" 10`

It gives this error

```
printf.hs:37:19:
Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints:
  (Format a0) arising from a use of `showManyP' at printf.hs:37:19-27
  (Num a0) arising from the literal `10' at printf.hs:37:34-35
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the second argument of `($)', namely `showManyP "%d" 10'
In the expression: putStrLn $ showManyP "%d" 10
In an equation for `main': main = putStrLn $ showManyP "%d" 10
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

The actual file begins here:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
import Data.List (intercalate,isPrefixOf)
class Showable a where
    showManyP :: String -> a

instance Showable String where
    showManyP str = str

instance (Showable s,Format a) => Showable (a->s) where
    showManyP str a = showManyP (format str a)

class Format a where 
    format :: String -> a -> String

instance Format String where
    format str a = replace "%s" str a

instance Format Char where
    format str a = replace "%c" str [a]

instance Num a=>Format a where
    format str a = replace "%d" str (show a)

replace :: String -> String -> String -> String
replace f str value = intercalate value $ split str f

split :: String -> String -> [String] 
split [] f = [[]]
split str [] = [str] 
split str@(x:xs) f | isPrefixOf f str = [[],drop (length f) str]
                   | otherwise = let (y:ys) = split xs f
                                 in [x:y] ++ ys
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In ghc, When you enter a numeric constant like `10`, it can be any type that is an instance of `Num`.  If there are no additional type constraints, it is an undecided instance, and you must provide a specific type; i.e. `(10 :: Int)`.  Ghci is interactive, and it would be a pain to have to add types to numbers, so it helps you out by assuming that, in the absence of additional type constraints, that things that look like integers are of type `Integer`.  This is explained in the GHC User Guide [2.4.5. Type defaulting in GHCi](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#id582702)

According to the "2010 Haskell Report", in [4.3.4 Ambiguous Types, and Defaults for Overloaded Numeric Operations](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4), there is a `default` keyword that allows you to take advantage of this behavior in compiled modules.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Type defaulting _is_ enabled in compiled Haskell modules, equivalent to a declaration of `default (Integer, Double)`. However it is not applied in this case, because `Format` is not a standard class. (See your first link). In GHCi, however, this restriction is lifted.

Comment: Can you tell how to add default declaration for Format in the above case ..?