# Why does signature change after an assignment

Tags: haskell, ghci

Playing around in `ghci` I got the following expression: `unlines . map (\(a,b) -> show a ++ " " ++ show b)`

Now when I check it via `:t` I get:

```
> :t  unlines . map (\(a,b) -> show a ++ " " ++ show b)
unlines . map (\(a,b) -> show a ++ " " ++ show b)
  :: (Show a, Show a1) => [(a, a1)] -> String
```

So exactly as expected. But now if I try to assign it to some name, I get a more specific signature than the original one:

```
> let f = unlines . map (\(a,b) -> show a ++ " " ++ show b)
> :t f
f :: [((), ())] -> String
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: See also: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055146), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439163), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714697), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434808), [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799345), [6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262020), [7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655900), [8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003535). I'm honestly not sure which (if any) of these to mark this a duplicate of.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because of the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction), definitions of the form `x = ...` (no parameters) are given a monomorphic (i.e. non-polymorphic) type, which usually involves some defaulting as mentioned [in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15451531/98117).

To prevent this from happening, either add a type signature to your definition, or disable the monomorphism restriction using `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction`. You can add this to your [`.ghci` file](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html) to have it run automatically on startup until [it gets disabled by default in GHCi in some future version](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3202).

Comment: Or eta expand; i.e. `let f x = unlines . map (\(a,b) -> show a ++ " " ++ show b) $ x`

Answer (score 4):

Defaulting rules.

When you type stuff in GHCi, it attempts to apply default types. IIRC, for things with a `Num` constraint it picks `Integer`, for `Fractional` it picks `Double`, and for everything else it picks `()`.

If you write this in a Haskell source file and load it into GHCi, this doesn't happen (I believe).

I think you can also say something like `default Int` to change the defaulting rules on a per-module basis.